# Using a column in a Pandas dataframe as a lookup to choose a second column in the same df, twice, and then do a comparison on the results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to use data in a DF to retrieve data from other columns in the same DF, do some logical processing, and then write a new value back to the DF?

---

I have a Pandas dataframe which contains a column that I want to use as a lookup to pick a column out of three options - after I append a suffix to the value.

E.g.

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3A  Col4A  Col5A
1 Col3  Col3   1     -2      3
2 Col4  Col5   2     -3      4
3 Col3  Col4  -3      4     -5
. ...   ...   ...    ...    ...
```

So in row 1: I need to pick the string "Col3" out of `Col1`, append "A", and then get the value from `Col3A` (1).
Then for row 2: that should result in `Col4A` (-3).
Etc., for all rows.

Then do the same for `Col2` and have a second set of values (1, 4, 4, etc.).

Then take those two sets of numbers (`1, -3, -3, etc.` and `1, 4, 4, etc.`), and see if the sign has changed (`N, Y, Y, etc.`).

That output then needs to be saved in a new column like this:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3A  Col4A  Col5A  Col6
1 Col3  Col3   1     -2      3     N
2 Col4  Col5   2     -3      4     Y
3 Col3  Col4  -3      4     -5     Y
. ...   ...   ...    ...    ...    ...
```

---

My attempt to solve this so far has mostly thrown memory errors (shape of my actual df is only `(91376, 121)`), and I feel there must be a better way...

```py
df['Col6'] = np.where(
    np.sign(df[df['Col1'] + 'A']) != np.sign(df[df['Col2'] + 'A']),
    'Y',
    'N'
)
```

I don't want to have to write an exhaustive tree of `np.where`'s, to capture all 9 combinations of columns, so any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
a = df.lookup(df.index, df['Col1'] + 'A')
b = df.lookup(df.index, df['Col2'] + 'A')
print (a)
[ 1 -3 -3]
print (b)
[1 4 4]

df['Col6'] = np.where(np.sign(a) != np.sign(b), 'Y', 'N')
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3A  Col4A  Col5A Col6
1  Col3  Col3      1     -2      3    N
2  Col4  Col5      2     -3      4    Y
3  Col3  Col4     -3      4     -5    Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as @jezrael but wrote a custom lookup function.

```
def look_up(df, col, suffix):
    encode = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
    columns = [str(col) + suffix for col in encode.columns]
    encode_array = encode.values
    data_array = df[columns].values
    return np.einsum('ij,ij-> i', encode_array, data_array)
```

The rest is pretty much the same:

```
a = look_up(df, 'Col1', 'A')
b = look_up(df, 'Col2', 'A')
print (a)
[ 1 -3 -3]
print (b)
[1 4 4]

df['Col6'] = np.where(np.sign(a) != np.sign(b), 'Y', 'N')
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3A  Col4A  Col5A Col6
1  Col3  Col3      1     -2      3    N
2  Col4  Col5      2     -3      4    Y
3  Col3  Col4     -3      4     -5    Y
```

The custom look_up function is ~28 times faster for the above problem but probably not worth the extra effort.